# String and matrix

Tags: tcl

what is needleString and haystackString? How they are used?

Also need to write a pakage of Matrix which contains procedure of multiplication and Inverse.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your first question refers to [`string first`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M8). The *needleString* is the (presumably short) string to search for, and the *haystackString* is the (presumably longer) string to search within. The names are chosen with reference to “searching for a needle in a haystack” (an idiomatic English phrase, indicating a difficult search — though one that a computer system would do better at) and are far easier to remember than *string1 string2*. (After all, who would search in a needle for a haystack?)

In your second question, please consider using the [math::linearalgebra](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/linalg.html) package from [Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/). The `::math::linearalgebra::matmul` is particularly relevant.

The inverse of a matrix is a rather more complicated operation, and doesn't (currently) have a single high-quality implementation. I suggest either writing code based on Gauss–Jordan elimination, or using the [invert operation from the math page of the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/778) (though beware if the matrix is large; the Wiki code is *not* optimal).